# Bug in the "reputation" view of my profile

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-history

There is a bug in the ["reputation" view](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86072/legec?tab=reputation) of my profile :

- in "today"'s posts, a ghost entry is displayed
  (note: reloading the page with `Ctrl+R` at the moment of the screenshot did not make that ghost line disappear, but I now no longer see it. fwiw : I think it appeared when I clicked on the "reputation" link at a time when there was a badge announcing that I had gained some since my last viewing)
- there is a possible rendering issue when the title gets too long

the "0" scored entry is "yesterday"'s posts also looks suspicious.

[image: bug in reputation view]

Comment: It disappears when you reload and only happens when you have new items in the view, but this is indeed annoying and broken.

Comment: ok, "bugs as expected" I guess, then ;)

Comment: @LeGEC "bugs that have been reported to SE but SE haven't done anything to fix them". Which I guess you can also shorten to "expected".

Comment: Also reported on MSE: [Ghost (nonexistent) votes in reputation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377620/ghost-nonexistent-votes-in-reputation-tab)

Comment: The second bug (regarding long titles) has also been reported on MSE: [In the "Reputation" tab of my "Activity" page, a long post title starts on a completely new line with improper alignment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376859/in-the-reputation-tab-of-my-activity-page-a-long-post-title-starts-on-a-com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ghost items" issue seems to have been fixed.

For the alignment part on long question titles, however, the issue is still present.

Testing in my browser (Firefox 102 on linux), it looks like setting a max-width by hand on the `div` that encloses the question title can fix things, and is probably portable to most of the supported navigators :

[image: screen capture of GUI with a manual tweak]

One other option could be to use a `display: grid` container rather than a `display: flex` (again: I don't know what browser support you have in mind).