# Pretty big "serial voting was reversed" hit. Why did it take a long time to occur?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I've had votes reversed in the past, no big deal, but it was always a few here or there. I understand that it happens. It's never ever happened like this though.

[image]

Is this a case where some user has, over a very long time, voted on a lot of my content? If this is the case why wasn't it caught and rectified earlier?

---

Ok, things have cooled a bit and I see others have also been affected. 1.6K is only 160 votes, but still, it would take some time for a single person to distribute 160 "extra" votes. So are we talking about a voting ring or similar? What's the benefit of contributing seemingly random votes?

Comment: Same as this: [What should / can / may I do when losing reputation points due to serial voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419980)?

Comment: @SuperStormer IMO not really a duplicate of that post since I'm asking why it may've taken, presumably, a long time to happen, not what can I do about it. I understand there's not much I can do since this is how the system is designed to work.

Comment: probably linked to the -300 I also got as "voting corrected". Maybe a big cartel of suspicious accounts was discovered recently.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Right, after reading through some of the comments on the dupe SuperStormer suggested I think the posts are related. It looks like a large site-wide crackdown happened.

Comment: One of [What should / can / may I do when losing reputation points due to serial voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419980) and this post should be closed as a duplicate of the other, since they're presumably related to the same large scale voting reversal event. Both are asking "what happened" so I don't see any point in there being 2 separate questions.

Comment: There was a post about a big voting correction event due to a large sockpuppets network about a year ago but I can't for the life of me find it. Many users also "lost" thousands of rep points at the time. Does anyone remember this event or have a link to that post?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Are you referring to this one: [Massive serial voting reversal has occurred](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412963)? The roomba got to it.

Comment: @cigien YES, that's it. Thank you! I was going to use it as a dup-target for these two posts but it's already deleted. Perhaps they should be closed as a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408724/8967612) as was the case with the one that got deleted?

Comment: So.... basically over some longer timeframe than the normal script runs to detect serial-voting, an investigation was done and some other non-serial votes were deemed fraudulent and a lot of us are victims of circumstance. Note, none of the suggested or discussed posts are IMO suitable dupe targets as I'm specifically asking *why* wasn't the serial voting detected earlier. It's clear why the votes were reversed.

Comment: I didn't get any votes reversed.  Why am I not getting a fair share of the dodgy upvotes?  Is there somewhere I have to register to get the socks/rings/scripts to send me votes? :)

Comment: @MartinJames haha, if I only knew where you sign you up.

Comment: @cigien No offense. Just some considerations! If you look at things from a distance a lot of questions here are duplicates. The closer you get, things get clearer from obscure. A duplicate is clearly defined. It is a duplicate of something without a range of interpretation. For example 5 is a duplicate of 5. 6 is not a duplicate of 5. But some could say 6 is 5+1 and therefore is a duplicate. For these two questions 1. <https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419980/what-should-can-may-i-do-when-losing-reputation-points-due-to-serial-voting> and  ... to be continued  ...

Comment: 2. <https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419983/pretty-big-serial-voting-was-reversed-hit-why-did-it-take-a-long-time-to-occu>.  The first one asks what can I do, the second one asks why did it take a long time to occur. Yesterday I searched more the 3 hours everything to get an answer and also provided some posts as links in my question. I at least was not able to find a sufficient existing answer!

Comment: *"If this is the case why wasn't it caught and rectified earlier?"* -- in my business, the person who asks this is usually assigned to chair the committee that is responsible for the work for fixing the problem. Good luck ;)

Comment: You should at least get the galea badge (as opposed to the mortarboard badge). Get the maximum negative reputation of the day on SO.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Too bad there is no cap for negative reputation "earned" in a day

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> Is this a case where some user has, over a very long time, voted on a lot of my content?

Yes.  Specifically, it appears that the user was targeting posts from particular users for voting and other actions.  To be clear: **we have no reason to believe you did anything wrong here**.

> If this is the case why wasn't it caught and rectified earlier?

The user who cast these votes has deliberately taken steps to evade automated serial voting detection (I'm being deliberately vague here to avoid giving advice on how to do this) and to cast doubt on whether their voting was indeed targeted.  In fact, a smaller number of their votes to you *were* previously reversed, but they've since experimented and learned how to avoid automated reversals (despite warnings from moderators not to target votes in this manner).

Eventually, a moderator investigating a serial-voting flag found sufficient evidence that the warnings were not being heeded and that the user's voting, as a whole, was not organic. They escalated to the Community Management team, who can see individual votes.  A community manager investigated the details of the voting and concluded that this user's voting was indeed targeted, then performed a bulk invalidation of a large portion of the user's votes.

We apologize for this taking long enough for it to build up to this level, and we recognize that it can feel like an undeserved kick in the teeth.  You were one of ~8 users who received at least 100 of the votes reversed in this action.

Comment: Yeah, it was certainly a big "oof". I also wasn't concerned if I had done anything wrong because if I had I wouldn't be finding out about via a mysterious loss in rep. I was mostly just very surprised by the volume of it. Any ideas at all what possibly made my posts targets, other than chance?

Comment: So, if I am reading the correctly, the user in question was going to some significant lengths to hide *up votes*? I know nobody can or should reveal details here, but I can't help being curious about a user's motivations. Why go through this trouble to increase someone else's rep?

Comment: @Mark yes the users aim is to hide upvotes, but not just all upvotes (which are hidden from normal users anyway) but ones where they voted on their actual target who they wanted to increase the reputation of.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I get that part. The question is why would someone want to increase the reputation of someone else?

Comment: @Mark maybe it is a sock puppet and they are increasing their own reputation, maybe they are buying and selling reputation, see: [Don't be that account: buying and selling reputation and bounties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410831/dont-be-that-account-buying-and-selling-reputation-and-bounties).

Comment: I guess I'm one of the 8, [got -2850 of rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSQ1L.png) ;) I can't understand why someone would give me 285 dummy votes. Also, I often have +0 votes above the 200 cap, are those taken into account in the calculation (might this mean that there are even more than 285 dummy votes?). Was this a single user or multiple accounts?

Comment: My belief (without having seen the individual votes as the CM did) is that the user was misguided rather than trying to hide a "real" vote target.  Think of the people who "thank" people for an answer by voting up a bunch of the other posts from their profile (not quite what was happening here, but a very similar end result).  I'm also a bit constrained by trying to describe this in a way that wouldn't allow someone to work out who the user was.

Comment: @mozway it does take that into account, but the reputation history page UI is, arguably, broken.  289 votes to your account were reversed.  285 of those were on non-deleted posts.  However, despite what's shown there, your reputation dropped from 102982 to 101594 as a result of the recalculation, a drop of only 1388.  Drew's actual reputation drop, similarly, was only 1258.

Comment: Thanks for the info, It's a bit of a relief if this was in fact more of a misguided than malicious voting, but still, that's a **lot** of votes (yeah, I have a fan!). How do you make the difference with a user that likes a particular topic, "follows" some of the top users and votes on them often (I have had a few times users telling me they liked my answers and were "studying" them)?

Comment: @mozway that difficulty is part of why it took so long...we wanted to be sure there was a problem before reversing anything. The short answer is: CMs look through voting and other logs to build up a more complete picture of how the voting occurred, and then apply their human judgement. That said, "following" someone to vote on their posts can be problematic, because it means that their answers are getting an unfair advantage over users that don't have followers.  But it's tricky to differentiate between that and closely following a tag in which you post a lot...that's where the CMs come in.

Comment: @RyanM Might I suggest that if a user is going to take such a large rep hit, you drop them a note before you do it?

Comment: @mozway akrun also expressed losing a bunch of votes today, so I suspect these users may be more "fans" of the top-N users on the leaderboards.

Comment: @DavidG We've done that in at least one case, though it sort of awkwardly backfired when it turned out that what we thought was going to be a ~1.5k rep loss ended up being...20 rep.  They'd hit the rep cap a lot, and our tooling doesn't know how much it'll be in advance.  That said, that's a good point, and something we can definitely consider doing (maybe immediately after the recalc, once we know the size of the drop).

Comment: @RyanM yes I imagine that must always be tricky to decide. Not a big deal in fine

Comment: @DrewReese Could be, I just saw that I'm dropping from #1 to #20 (I should be immune for a while) :p

Comment: Ugh. So effectively this is Stack Overflow simping. I can't put a nicer description to it, that is the 21st century definition of what is happening here. Why can't people contain themselves. It's one thing to want to attach to a mentor, it's another to want to shower them with gifts. Way over the line, and thus... a ban offence, IMO. You can't shake people out of that state of mind without a shock.

Comment: "bulk invalidation of a large portion" why not *all* of them? Why was the user account not deleted for such a gross violation of SO guidelines?

Comment: @Nick *"why not all of them?"* The CM handling the escalation made a judgement call as to the best way to separate the targeted votes from the non-targeted votes, in order to limit the disruption caused.  *"Why was the user account not deleted for such a gross violation of SO guidelines?"* We do not generally delete user accounts unless virtually *everything* they've contributed is in violation of the rules.  Even the worst repeat offenders are indefinitely suspended rather than having their accounts deleted.

Comment: "it sort of awkwardly backfired when it turned out that what we thought was going to be a ~1.5k rep loss ended up being...20 rep" The rep cap doesn't affect tag scores though, so that's a reduction of 150 points (though someone hitting the rep cap that hard likely has more than enough score for a gold badge in their main tags).

Comment: 160 Votes on one User, 285 Votes on another one, that's really a lot of Votes on one singular Answerer each time, => "*strange*" that the System doesn't detect that Pattern earlier as being "suspicious", ... and simply prevents it with some hard-coded Threshold-Cap at 10 Upvotes maybe from one User to the different Answers from one same Answerer, maybe per Month or 6 Months or per Year... :surprised:

Comment: @chivracq I would suspect a detection like that would get ignore due to all the false positives. I hang out in mostly a single tag where a majority of the questions are answered by a few people, I upvote answer accordingly, most of my up votes have likely gone to 3-4 people in the lua tag.

Comment: @Mark - *My own pure speculation - not based on any actual data.* If someone comes with a new illicit technique for mass upvoting of their own puppets without raising suspicion - they apparently need to test it first. High rep people seem to be convenient targets.  This way puppets are not exposed at an early stage.

Comment: Come on, everyone knows the trick to avoid detection is rubbing your belly and patting your head while walking in a clockwise circle under a waxing gibbous moon. It's not _that_ secret.

Comment: @chivracq There are certainly multiple users I cross paths with a lot whose content I have updated, probably in the hundreds of times in total. The _system_ should not consider that voting fraudulent, because it's not; each vote was cast on the content independent of anything else, which is Ryan's point. It necessarily takes a human to discern where _apparently legitimate_ voting constitutes fraud.

Comment: @RyanM In retrospect I *do actually* recall intermittent periods (*i.e. a few days in a row every now and then*) where immediately (*within a few minutes*) after midnight UTC I would receive an influx of about 3-5 upvotes, always on answers I'd just provided *that* day. It felt odd, the timing. I OFC can't see who provided these votes, but this is a bit of a pattern that I could discern. I had considered making a meta post if I should be concerned, but to be honest wouldn't know how to phase it as a question other than a "should I be concerned?" which isn't that great.

Comment: @RyanM Perhaps this is information the Mods can take and pass on to SO for future investigations.

Comment: I also saw initially -2800, then after a few minutes and a refresh, -700. For a [reputation drop of... 0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc?tab=reputation).

Comment: @VonC the initial -2800 might be [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419030/208273) - mostly seen with upvotes but could presumably apply to voting corrections as well.  73 votes to your account were reversed, but there's no sign of the remaining 3 on the reputation page (not sure why).  And yes, after the invalidation, your reputation was recalculated from 1149093 to... 1149093.  Out of curiosity, how did you figure out that your reputation didn't actually drop?  You're correct, I just don't know how you figured it out without mod tools.

Comment: @RyanM I had other windows with my old reputation (not refreshed), and my new Windows with reputation listing -700. Both had the same rep.

Comment: @TylerH WANING gibbous! I told you, a *waning* gibbous moon! And *anti*clockwise!!

Comment: @AJM Oops. Did I just summon Cthulhu?

Comment: @TylerH I think it's worse than that. By walking around in the wrong direction, you may have just summoned Uhluhtc.

Comment: @Nick Trust me, if they invalidated *all the things* [people would notice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408562/2370483)

Comment: @Machavity ouch! good to see it was able to be corrected though.

Comment: How confident are you and the moderators that this is  "targeted" and "warranted reversal"?

Comment: @TheMaster Pretty confident. Community managers have gotten pretty good of late at noting patterns and it didn't take them long to find this one. No invalidations are done lightly, but we all take voting fraud very seriously as well. It's unfortunate it happens, but I would say a significant chunk of users get hit by a reversal now and then. The only difference here was the size.

Comment: Affirmative... it was was size of the reversal that surprised me and I was wondering how/why the normal smaller patterns weren't caught earlier. Trade secrets aside it seems in this case an attack vector was possibly being tested out and it took time to establish the pattern and determine the extent.